# How to increase maximum upload file size of LOAD DATA INFILE query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am loading a text file into database using load data query. There is no problem uploading the file size upto 2GB But i couldn't upload the files more then 2 GB. My query is given below

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mytempfile' INTO TABLE feeds
```

How can i increase my maximum upload file size in mysql?
Please advise..

Comment: edit php.ini and mysql.cnf and increase values of upload_max_filesize and max_allowed_packet

Comment: you can't upload file for more than 2047MB.

Comment: Just split you txt file

Comment: What happens when you try to load a 2 GB file? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: @vodich how can i update this in my live server

Comment: @Ike Walker mysql gone away load infile This is my error

Comment: @Toretto i need to upload maximum size of files into database this is my requirement.

Comment: If you decide to break the file down into smaller chunks as @RobertRozas suggests, I recommend using pt-fifo-split: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-fifo-split.html

Comment: @Ike Walker how can i use in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a answer. i can split big size of zip files into small size of multi files. if we load large size of file database dump problem occurred.  its working great with me. Cheers.