# Importing a very large text (not CSV) file into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, text, import, phpmyadmin

I have a >3GB .txt file with text in the form of sentences, each sentence in a new line. I also have a very simple MySQL table with the following structure:

**tblcontext**

```
si_no => INT(11); unsigned; autoincrement
context => VARCHAR(190); unique; fulltext
```

From the txt source, each line (i.e. sentence) of text needs to go into **tblcontext** as a new value for the **context** field. I could simply use the import functionality built into PHPMyAdmin to import the file but my source is not a csv file. I cannot convert the txt into csv because every sentence could have inline commas and other punctuation marks which could mess up my input by potentially dividing each line into multiple lines. Is there any way I could import a plain txt into the table telling PHPMyAdmin to treat newline character and not comma as the delimiter?

I considered using PHP for this but since the source file is just too big, I tested a simple read before performing the actual import. Here's my attempt:

```
$handle = fopen("en.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) { echo $line; }
    fclose($handle);
} else { echo 'could not import'; }
```

But the simple read above froze my computer! I'm sure doing the INSERT using PHP will be even slower which is why I am looking for some way to use the PHPMyAdmin's IMPORT function hoping it should be faster. There are around 50m lines in the text file in question.

Comment: what about LOAD DATA INFILE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: It refused to work saying "You probably tried to upload a file that is too large."

Comment: PHPMyAdmin has a limit, which you can change, but I'm not aware of a limit if you use a mysql terminal prompt

Comment: actually there seems to be a limit of 2GB, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813750/how-to-increase-maximum-upload-file-size-of-load-data-infile-query